# How to get inputs before submiting and put it on textArea LARAVEL

Tags: laravel

my input for example :

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">New Name Offers :</label>
                <input  name="newNameOffers" class="form-control" id="newNameOffers">
            </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">From Email :</label>
                <input  name="fromEmail" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" id="fromEmail">
            </div>
```

How can i put it on text area .... 
That my textArea :

```
<textarea  class="form-control" name="HEADER" id="HEADER" rows="11">i need to dispay my values here <textarea>
```

(i need to put the values not the name of variable)

Comment: Do you want to put the value in real time? If yes, then you need to use javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to make a simple form for you. You can modify it as you wish. For this, you need to take help of javascript or other similar front end technologies. However, if your requirement is just to take the value to back end then you can get both value `$request->newNameOffers` and `$request->fromEmail` then you can concatenate and store in your desired way.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var val1 = document.getElementById("newNameOffers").value;
  var val2 = document.getElementById("fromEmail").value;
  var res =  val1 +' '+ val2;
  document.getElementById("HEADER").innerHTML = res;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

newNameOffers:<br>
<input  name="newNameOffers" onChange="myFunction()" class="form-control" id="newNameOffers">
<br>
fromEmail:<br>
<input  name="fromEmail" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" onChange="myFunction()" id="fromEmail">

<p>Click the button to alert the contents of the text area.</p>

<!-- <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button> -->
<br>
<textarea id="HEADER"></textarea>

<script>

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah that good sir thank you, but i have text in my textArea :

<textarea id="HEADER">i have a code html here in my text area and i want to add mot variables here </textarea>

Comment: and i need to put it without onclick="myFunction()"

Comment: i need to add variables in my textarea without change the content

Comment: you can call onChange in each input. I have updated the snippet. Is that what you are looking @HamzaBrinsi

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to put it using Laravel, You can do it in the front-end(JavaScript, JQuery, Vue.js, React) itself.

Comment: Yeah i put it with javaScript sir, but i need to add variables in my textarea without change the content